# filter model results based on nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an API call that returns the following (in simplest form):

```
App_Group {
   id: 1,
   apps: [{
     id :1,
     status: 'Active'},
     {
     id :2,
     status: 'Retired'}
   ]
```

I am looking to create a scope (or possibly another, better solution), that allows me to (upon an API flag such as `&active=true`) filter the nested attribute `apps` to display only apps that have a status of 'Active'.

After some trial and error, the best I could come up with is:

```
scope :active_apps, lambda { |id| joins(:apps).where(apps: {status:'Active'}).where(id:id)}
```

`AppGroup.active_apps(123)` returns multiple results(one for each 'active' attribute in apps), and the apps attribute has every result in it.

Is there a way to get my desired results?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The answer lied in the AppGroup model

```
has_many :apps
#added the following
has_many :active_apps, -> { where(status: 'Active') }, :class_name => 'App'
```

So instead of scoping inside the AppGroup model, I name scoped in the App model and I just call that when i need it.